# image margin-bottom interferes with line height

Tags: html, css

I want to align an image left and let the text float around it. This is my basic code:

```
<p>
  <img style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;margin-bottom:15px" src="/image/logo.png" alt=""
  width="307" height="63" />Here is the floating text..
</p>
```

The problem is that the margin-bottom adds up the remaining line-height

[image]

How do you deal with that?

**Edit:** I tried now

```
<img style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;margin-bottom:15px;height:4em" src="/image/logo.png" alt="" />
```

So that it is exactly 4 lines long, but that did not work

Comment: For your edited part, now the height is 4 lines + 15px. So try to do it with `height: calc(4em - 15px);`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
<img style="float: left; margin-right: 1em;margin-bottom:1em;height:4em" src="/image/logo.png" alt="" />
```

Or in case that line-height is modified:

```
<p style="line-height:108%">
   <img style="float: left; margin-right: 1.08em;margin-bottom:1.08em;height:4.32em" src="/image/logo.png" alt="" />
```